# Change to the last created, or last alphanumeric directory.

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have folders that have the following structure:

```
/folder/processed_2013_0101
/folder/processed_2013_0223
```

etc.

What I'm wanting to do, is write a batchscript to move all of the files out of the most recent processed folder. 
How would I go about specifying which folder that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f %%i IN ('dir /b /ad \folder\processed_*') DO SET mrf=%%i
ECHO Most recent=%mrf%
```

Then `move %mrf%\* destination`

wherever destination is...

Comment: Cheers - so that sorts the dir by last access ascending?

Comment: That's the default order. You could add `/on` if you wish (order by name.) the variable `mrf` is simply set to the last entry on the list.

Comment: But you used addition keywords here. "last accessed" is not necessarily the last alphabetic. It may be that if you really want `last accessed` you'd need to add the `/od /ta` switch